# Emitting Array of objects with delay between each object

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an array of object and I would like to emit each object and then 5 seconds delay. at the end only after all objects were emitted then complete.

Here is my code which doesn't quite do that,

```
public class SequentialLoopWithDelayTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Start: " + DateTime.now().toString());
        rx.Observable.from(new String[] {"Test_1", "Test_2", "Test_3"}) 
        .flatMap(str -> {
            return printObservable(str)
            .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        })
            .subscribe(results -> { 
                System.out.println("End: " + DateTime.now().toString());
        });

    }

    private static rx.Observable<String> printObservable(String str) {
        System.out.println(DateTime.now().toString() + ", " + str);
        return rx.Observable.just(str);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Notice: I can't use any blocking!

Thanks :-)

Comment: The more specific your description, the more likely you are to find help. Telling us your code doesn't (quite) work is not helpful - you wouldn't be here if it worked perfectly. What, specifically, is wrong?

Comment: This code just run through the array, but doesn't do any delay and doesn't reach the 'subscribe' at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip with an observable created using interval

```
List<String> testList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Test_1", "Test_2", "Test_3"});
Observable<String> test = Observable.from(testList).zipWith(Observable.interval(0,5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (a,b) -> a);
test.subscribe(value -> System.out.println(value + " Emitted at : " + DateTime.now().toString()), error->{},()-> System.out.print("Completed"));
```

Full code

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

class TimerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> testList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Test_1", "Test_2", "Test_3"});
        Observable<String> test = Observable.from(testList).zipWith(Observable.interval(0,5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (a,b) -> a);
        test.subscribe(value -> System.out.println(value + " Emitted at : " + DateTime.now().toString()), error->{},()-> System.out.print("Completed"));

        try {
            // Sleep so the program doesn't exit immediately
            Thread.sleep(50000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

To delay the completion

```
Observable<String> test2 = test.concatWith(Observable.<String>empty().delay(2000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
```

Comment: It looked promising, but eventually when I ran it - it only printed the first iteration and then stuck.

Comment: That's strange. I've edited the answer with the full code snippet that works for me.

Comment: oh, sorry my bad. I didn't see the 'sleep'.

Comment: How to extend your answer so when it reaches the "complete" part in 'subscribe' it waits another 2 seconds and only then prints "complete" ?

Comment: Works well!! Thank you again :-)